# How to change the OLEDB connection information using Script Task?

Tags: ssis

I've an OLEDB Connection, I want this connection to be changed dynamically in the script. I am getting  the information of this OLEDB Connection using the following code:

```
ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections["VendorDB"];
        DbConnection conn = null;
        if (cm.CreationName == "OLEDB")
        {
            Wrap.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100 cmParams =
            cm.InnerObject as Wrap.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100;
            conn = cmParams.GetConnectionForSchema() as DbConnection;
        }
        else
        {
            conn = cm.AcquireConnection(null) as DbConnection;
        }

        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        MessageBox.Show(conn.ConnectionString.ToString());
```

I need to change this connection information (like I want to change the Initial Catalog etc.) and want this changed information to retain throughout the package. How to do so?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you are attempting to accomplish with this? If the goal is simply to change the value of the connection string at run time, an expression would probably be easiest.

Comment: To be more descriptive, I have to do different settings for different regions, therefore I want different configuration settings for each region. According to my understanding, config files are loaded in the start and what I'm trying to do here is to change the connection string dynamically.

Comment: Would this be based on values in a data flow (row 1 to region a, Row 2 to region B) or a foreach scenario where you need to change the connection for all of the members of the set?

Comment: yes the later one, i need to change the connection for all of the members of the set.

Answer (score 1):

I would resolve this issue by using a combination of things

- First I would define an SSIS Variable as indicated [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-introducing-variables/)
- The I would make the connection string an expression as indicated [here](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2006/03/11/ssis-nugget_3a00_-setting-expressions.aspx)
- And change the variable via script as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064438/how-to-modify-the-variable-in-ssis)

The first step is relatively easy:

Open the Variables tab (right click inside control flow and click Variables) and add the variable you want (Maybe String for your connection string)

Make an expression using your newly defined variable.
Use the code from the third link to change the value at runtime.

```
Dts.Variables("myVariable").Value = @"C:\Test2.txt";

Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
```